# Asyncronous validation directive on blur angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that validate mail given by the user by asynchronous web request. It works fine but the problem is that the asynchronous calls are made each time the user type a character, I would like the asynchronous calls to be done only on blur, how can I do that?

Here is the code for the directive :

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('usernameValidator', function($http, $q) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$asyncValidators.username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            return $http.post('/username-check', {username: viewValue}).then(
                function(response) {
                    if (!response.data.validUsername) {
                        return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            );
        };
    }
};
});
```

I have tried to put everything in a bloc

```
element.bind('blur', function() { ... })
```

But when the code is inside element.bind bloc I have a totally weird behavior : first time I focus the input, no asynchronous calls, when I blur no asynchronous calls, when I come back the focus on the input I have asynchronous calls for each character..

Answer (score 2):

try to add to your directive in HTML `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` as demonstrated at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#!, so your directive looks like:

```
<input ng-model="your_model"
       username-validator
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```